# How to generate List of previous 6 months with year from DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to .net MVC. How can I generate list of last 6 months with years in .net MVC. The only thing  have is DateTime.Now and i need

`ViewBag.Months=List of months with years`

Comment: what hv u tried till now??

Comment: this will give you a list of 6 `DateTime` objects for each month (same day as today): `Enumerable.Range(0,6).Select(i => System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i-6))` - just extract the `.Month` and `.Year` components out of them ... this is of course assuming you want the last months without the current - also not that you should extract the `DateTime.Now` out ... you could get unlucky and the date/month switches in between calls ... would be a very nasty **heisenbug**

Comment: @AwaisMahmood I am just able to find month by using Month=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)    But I am not able to find list of months.

Comment: @Carsten: thank you...it helps

Comment: It's strange that people answer at a poor quality question just for rep.

Comment: @Kosmo, poor quality or no, if I can understand the question enough to provide an answer, I do, and not for rep. It's crazy, I know, but I actually just like helping people. What's the world coming to, right?

Comment: @Kosmo ... it's called being helpful (and wanting the rep) ... what's really strange is the meta-discussions around this :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can create the list of DateTime values using an Enumerable.Range lambda expression.  You will need to extract the month/year strings using ToString("MM/yyyy") on each value in the enumeration.  Take a look at this fiddle for a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5CQNnZ

---

```
var lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
                              .Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6))
                              .Select(date => date.ToString("MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I need.
I am new at stack overflow and not have enough reputation to give +1.

Answer (score 7):

This is all you need.

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
ViewBag.Months = Enumerable.Range(1, 6).Select(i => now.AddMonths(-i).ToString("MM/yyyy"));
```

Example Output (as of February 2016):

```
01/2016 
12/2015 
11/2015 
10/2015 
09/2015 
08/2015
```

You don't strictly need to set the `now` variable first, but it does serve to ensure that you don't roll over to a new month in the middle of processing. It would be an extremely unlikely bug, but could potentially happen.